# Using magic-trackpad for simple play/pause interface for movies or music

Tags: accessibility, magic-trackpad

Backstory...my mother-in-law fell and has a spinal injury (C5), and she has no finger use, just her arms.  I want to give her some control over her iPad to play or pause movies and music.  Anyone have a script to assign the play/pause button as a single tap to the magic-trackpad?

Also, any other simple yet clever scripts for handicap use with the trackpad would be most appreciated.

Thanks,
Don
donroy (at) gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the level of ability, but you could try the

1. Voice Control http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201936

or the

2. AssistiveTouch http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202658